# Unable to set progress bar progress twice in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiprogressview

I have `UIProgressView`.On begin to text edit for a `UITextField` I set the value of progress bar to 1 . Before that initially I make it progress to 0.1 .But it is setting progress only once. If I first set progress to 0.1 then after it does not set progress to 1.please tell me what is the issue ?

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    setViewBottomColor()

    var view:BottomView?

    if textField == textFieldEmail {
        view = self.bottomViewFirst
        view?.trackTintColor = Constant.AppColor.viewBottom
        view?.progressTintColor = Constant.AppColor.purpleViewColor

    }
    else if textField == textFieldPassword {
        view = self.bottomViewSecond
        view?.trackTintColor = Constant.AppColor.viewBottom
        view?.progressTintColor = Constant.AppColor.purpleViewColor
    }
    if view != nil {
        view?.setProgress(1, animated: true)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {
            view?.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: { (finish) in
        })
}
}

func setViewBottomColor() {

    self.bottomViewFirst.trackTintColor = Constant.AppColor.viewBottom
    self.bottomViewFirst.progressTintColor = Constant.AppColor.purpleViewColor
    self.bottomViewFirst?.setProgress(0.1, animated: false)
    self.bottomViewFirst?.layoutIfNeeded()

}
```

Comment: can you explain what is BottomView here?

Comment: BottomView:UIProgressView

Comment: check your IBOutlet connections once. Same code is working for me.

Comment: I am not able to do this issue.my outlets are correct

Comment: can you try the code I have posted below. change respective values as per your code if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check below code snippet I have used to check. It is working fine.

You may check few things:

1. All IBOutlets connections must be there.
2. If you are using custom UIProgressView as BottomView then you must changed both progress view class in xib/storyboard as well.
3. No Need to have view animation if for progress value change only.

   ```
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

       resetProgresses()
       var view = UIProgressView()

       if textField == t1 {
           view = self.progressBar
           view.trackTintColor = .red
           view.progressTintColor = .green

       }
       else if textField == t2 {
           view = self.progressBar2
           view.trackTintColor = .green //Constant.AppColor.viewBottom
           view.progressTintColor = .red//Constant.AppColor.purpleViewColor
       }

       if view != nil {
           view.setProgress(1, animated: true)
       }

     }

    func resetProgresses()  {
       self.progressBar?.setProgress(0.1, animated: true)
       self.progressBar2?.setProgress(0.1, animated: true)

     }
   ```

Comment: I am using animation because i want to change the speed

Comment: can you tell me a way to make my code more optimized

Comment: even with animation it is working. Is this code worked for you? We can look to optimize once its working :)